# Fill div with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div`:

```
<div id="shoppingBasket">
</div>
```

Using Javascript or Jquery how would I fill this with the default text:

`you have no products in your shopping basket.`

What I mean by default text is I would want to change the text after they clicked a product. so maybe the default text in a variable and then included in the div via JavaScript or Jquery, which would allow the variable to be manipulated.

Comment: What do you mean by default text?

Comment: I think reading a basic tutorial on JQuery will cover this for you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or javascript [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

With jquery, using jQuery [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$('#shoppingBasket').text("you have no products in your shopping basket.");
```

With Javascript, using [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
document.getElementById("shoppingBasket").innerText = "you have no products in your shopping basket.";
```

Answer (score 8):

With jQuery this would be:

```
$('#shoppingBasket').text("you have no products in your shopping basket.");
```

with regular javascript:

```
document.getElementById("shoppingBasket").innerHTML = "you have no products in your shopping basket.";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function fillwithtext(text, elementID) {
    document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = text;
}
```

How's that?