# Fill div with html using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my problem:

I have a div:

```
<div id="legend"></div>
```

and I want to fill it, under certain conditions, with this other code:

```
<p>Showing results....
    Key:
    <img src="/....">&lt;=1
    &nbsp;<img src="/...">&lt;=2
    &nbsp;<img src="/...">&lt;=3
    &nbsp;<img src="/...">&lt;=4
    &nbsp;<img src="/...">&lt;=5

<p>
```

As you can see this is a legend and the main issue I think is that I have double quotes that cannot be easily included using for instance the solution here:
[Fill div with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756448/fill-div-with-text)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are these "certain conditions" you speak of?

Comment: Here is a hint. Use `.html()` rather than `.text()`

Comment: Does the _results_ come from a database? I mean, there can be a different number of results?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By my understanding, you are trying to do something like this:

```
$("#legend").text("Your HTML here");
```

To insert HTML, you should use `.html()`, HOWEVER it would be far more efficient to just use [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) like so:

```
document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = "Your HTML here";
```

Now, you also mention having problems with double-quotes. Well, there are two possible solutions.

1: Use single-quotes around your string: `'<img src="/..." />'`
2: Escape the quotes: `"<img src=\"/...\" />"`

And one more thing: If those newlines are actually in your HTML to insert, you can't have a multi-line string in JavaScript. You have two options here too:

1: Escape the newline:

```
"<p>\
    Hello, world!\
</p>"
```

2: Concatenate:

```
"<p>\n"
    +"Hello, world!\n"
+"</p>"
```

Comment: I think that these information will help! Thank you! I am going to try and let you know.

Comment: Basically my whole problem was that I did not know that I could not have multi-line strings. Now everything works great! Thank you very much Kolin.

Comment: Glad I could help :) If my answer was useful, please consider marking it as Accepted by clicking the check mark under my post's score ^_^

Comment: I suppose I can't because this is my first post here.
Under your post's score I can't see any check mark. I only see your gold, silver and bronze badges. :)

Comment: That's my user box. You should look to the left of the first sentence in the answer, you should see it there.

Comment: Could you please explain why selecting with `class e.g. querySelector()` not working ?

Answer (score 6):

Assemble your html code in a variable according to your conditions (which we do not know), then use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set it to the element.

```
var yourHtml = "your html";
$("#legend").html("yourHtml");
```

As for dealing with the quotes, you can either use single quotes in variable, such as:

```
var yourHtml = '<img src="/yourimgr.png">';
```

or you can escape the double quotes:

```
var yourHtml = "<img src=\"/yourimgr.png\">";
```

Comment: You must be psychic. How else would you know what the "certain conditions" mentioned in the questions are?

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, is not clear enough.
But that is not the problem.
I only need a way to encode that html I guess.
I tried with this
    $("#id").append('<p>hello</p>')
and it worked. 
The problem is that the html to append is too 'complex'.
Is my problem a little bit more clear?

Comment: Now you just made it worse. This will literally print the string "yourHTML"

Comment: @Kolink My answer addresses the fact that OP needs to use `html()` method instead of `text()`, which OP points out. I also elabotared on the quotes. I does not regard how OP assembles the HTML, which does not look to be OP's issue

Comment: That was only one of three possible problems, and now you're just stealing my answer and using it as your own.

Comment: @Kolink That's a serious accusation. How many different ways of doing the string escape you think there are? Chill out. I think you were ahead of yourself downvoting my answer, but I did not even mention it. Remember the goal here is helping OP, I have no intention in jumping into petty rep disputes

Comment: thanks everyone guys! I am gonna give some try and ley you know

Comment: What I mean by that accusation is that you only edited your answer to include it after I had posted my own answer, and called you out on mistakes in yours. It's suspicious...

Comment: @user2283224: you can just store your complex string in variable. And then say `$('#id')append(variable)`

Comment: @Kolink Dude, you need to chill. You know how SO answers are built incrementally. Do you think the best answers here were written all at once? They would not see the light of day, if they were written at once, buried by the other answers. This is my last comment on this discussion, since it's very pointless. May you find peace...

Comment: Kolin in the next answer gave me the key. I did not know that I could not have multi-line strings in javascript. So I just added \ at the end of each line of code.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Hey people, I did not want you to fight for this! But thanks anyway to all of you. I would like to vote for the answers and give some feedbacks but I suppose I can't...since this is my first post here. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

1. Store your paragraph html in some string 
   `var str= <p>write your complete code here</p>`
2. `$('#legend').html(yourconditionSatisfies?str:'')`

Comment: Why not just put the whole thing in a conventional `if` statement?