# Can i supply HTML to populate a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a field in my model that contains static html (eg `<br />`).

When attempting to populate a div using jQuery using `$('#myField').html(fieldval)`, the browser throws and error that it received an Invalid or Unexpected token.  Is it possible to use jQuery to populate a div with html content?

```
$('#myDiv').html(@Html.Raw(modelvalue));
$('#myDiv').html(modelvalue);
```

Comment: Is that @Html.Raw Razor syntax?

Comment: If you’re using server side variable, you need to wrap it in quotes.

Comment: Use .text() method of jquery as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019621/fill-div-with-html-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Why not look at what the Razor output?  View source in the browser.  You'll see you have invalid html, eg `$('#myDiv').html(<br/>)` when it should obviously be `$('#myDiv').html("<br/>")`.   `@Html.Raw` will output as-is, while `@Model.Value` will escape for you (the opposite of how it worked in asp.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful to [prevent xss](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31463823/1026459) when introducing html into the page.

That said, to what what you are asking, make sure to quote the model value, as jQuery expects a string. This will work.

```
$('#myDiv').html('@(new HtmlString(modelvalue))');
```

However, you should not.

You should instead use either a WYSIWYG editing library or whitelist accepted html from the user prior to inserting raw HTML. If it is not user based, then you should create a separate view with its own html structure, and then populate that with sanitized values; and *then* insert that view instead of the raw string.

If it is the case that you are somehow writing to the response stream directly, and the string produced *is* sanitized then you probably wouldn't have asked this rather basic question, so I am ruling that out.