# Fill HTML element with text based on input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code right now works only to fill another input field. But I need it to fill a regular paragraph and not another input field. How can I do it?

```js
$(".first").on('keydown',function(){
  $(".second").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="first" placeholder="type here">
<input type="text" class="second" placeholder="here it is the reuslt">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to insert the text into the element.

[`id's`](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [`classes`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) can be used to specify either a **specific** element (`id`) or a **group** of elements (`class`). In the example below I added a class to change the colour of each `<p>` tag using css to red. In our JS we **select** on individual id's.

```js
//selecting on the insertTextHere id to specify the <p> tag to insert text into
$("#first").on('keyup', function() {
  $("#insertTextHere").text($(this).val());
});

//you can even set it up to revert back to the original text on click
$("#resetButton").on("click", function() {
  var resetText = "Type into input to overwrite this text";
  //insert original string as text
  $("#insertTextHere").text(resetText);
  //empty the input value
  $("#first").val("");
});
```

```css
.text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first" placeholder="type here">
<button id="resetButton" type="button">reset text</button>
<div>
  <p id="insertTextHere" class="text">Type into input to overwrite this text</p>
  <p class="text">This text will not be overwritten</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great, but can I specify which particular paragraph class should it fill? @master-yoda

Comment: Yes, ill update the answer now. I think you need to use text though as on keyup it will append each entered character again.

Comment: @DanielsV Add a class to your p tag to fill a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Form fields have a `value` property (`val()` method in JQuery). Regular elements have a `textContent` property (or in JQuery, a `text()` method).

Also, you should use `keyup` to get all the text as it is typed.

```js
$(".first").on('keyup',function(){
    $("#output").text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="first" placeholder="type here">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use '**input**' event instead of **keydown/keyup** - if user **pastes** the value **neither of them will work**. So use this instead:

```js
$('.inputClass').on('input', function() {
    $('.paragraphClass').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inputClass">
<p class="paragraphClass"></p>
```

Comment: Please don't link to code at 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your answer won't be as meaningful. Just insert a code snippet (7th button on the answer toolbar) into your answer to create an executable piece of code.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".first").on('keydown',function(){
    $('.selectorOfDOM').text($(this).val());
}
```

You can find similar question at this link. 
[Fill div with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756448/fill-div-with-text)

Comment: How is this answer any different or better that the other two that are already present?